# Calculate all possible routes between nodes where all nodes are touched only once? (Travelling Salesman)

Tags: java, path, grid, nodes, traveling-salesman

I'm trying to develop a Travelling Salesman-type program (in Java) and am trying to figure out the logic for a certain part, a brute-force approach for calculating the most efficient route between a set of nodes (Cities) where each node is touched only once.

I've defined a City class with the x/y co-ords and have an array of City instances, and a grid class to draw the grid.
Cities are visible on a grid, and numbered 0-i for their index in the City array
(In the sample grid there are 4 cities defined):

```
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · · · 1 · · · · · ·
· · 0 · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · · 3 · · · ·
· · · · · · 2 · · · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
· · · · · · · · · · · · · · · ·
```

There are many routes visible already (I believe 4! = 24):

- 0-1-2-3
- 0-2-1-3
- 2-0-1-3
- 2-3-1-0
- etc..

Is there a simple iterative/recursive method to obtain every possible path, given an array of cities and their co-ordinates, which I can use to determine the distance and list the most efficient route(s)?

Comment: Have you made an attempt? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, provide your attempt (code) first so users can help you build from that.

Comment: Thank you, I'll update the post with what I have.

Answer (score 1):

it's `Faculty(n)/2` if your distances are undirected or `Faculty(n)` if your connections are directed (meaning: distance a-->b differs from b-->a). It's called [Permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n)

dont forget [13! = 6227020800](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) and more than Integer.max_value, even 13! / 2 is more!

Comment: Thank you Martin! I got it working by implementing a "base-n" function with each "digit" an item in an integer array being the node number; the base n is the number of nodes. I ignore any array which contains the same "digit" (node number) twice - therefore ending up with arrays containing different orders of different nodes, and distance calculation and sorting was straightforward.